# Is it possible to get template from different directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using the same cshtml files in different projects so I would like to be able to share the same directory, the 'GeneralTemplates'. So using the `@Html.Partial("GeneralTemplates/_Header")` works like a charm. But with `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath("GeneralTemplates/_Breadcrumbs")` is doesn't work, this needs to be in the 'DisplayTemplates' directory and then this works `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath("_Breadcrumbs")`.

Does anyone has an solution for me to be able to have the file in the 'GeneralTemplates' directory? I was thinking maybe I'm able to get the List of Nodes for the Path but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an MVC issue than MvcSiteMapProvider, as MvcSiteMapProvider is using the default templated HTML helper behavior.

It took some searching, but I found a way to override this behavior by adding additional paths to the default MVC view search locations:
[Can I Add to the Display/EditorTemplates Search Paths in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581786/can-i-add-to-the-display-editortemplates-search-paths-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

```
System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine rve = (RazorViewEngine)ViewEngines.Engines
  .Where(e=>e.GetType()==typeof(RazorViewEngine))
  .FirstOrDefault();

string[] additionalPartialViewLocations = new[] { 
  "~/Views/GeneralTemplates/{0}.cshtml"
};

if(rve!=null)
{
  rve.PartialViewLocationFormats = rve.PartialViewLocationFormats
    .Union( additionalPartialViewLocations )
    .ToArray();
}
```

I don't believe it is possible to remove the `/DisplayTemplates` folder from the path, as that is a convention (to keep it separate from `/EditorTemplates`). So, the best you will be able to do is make a folder `~/Views/GeneralTemplates/DisplayTemplates/` using the configuration above.

Note that MVC checks for a `/DisplayTemplates` folder in the same directory as your view first before going to `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`, so you could also move them to the same view(s) directory where their corresponding HTML helpers are used.

I haven't tried, but it may also be possible to use a complete view path (i.e.  `~/Views/GeneralTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml`) when specifying the template.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath("~/Views/GeneralTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml")
```

**Important:** If you change the location of all of the templates like this, you will probably need to go through the recursive templates and change all of `DisplayFor` locations within them as well.

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Linq
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@foreach (var node in Model) { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node); @* // <-- Need to add the diplaytemplate here, too *@

    if (node != Model.Last()) {
        <text> &gt; </text>
    }
}
```

You *could* instead build custom HTML helpers that are non-templated to work around this issue if the other solutions don't work for you.

Comment: Thnx for your response! I've tried the first option, but it didn't work out (my GeneralTemplates is located in the `Views/Shared` folder). And using the complete path didn't work either. So I'm going to create the custom HTML helper.